# parent content height not expanding with tabs content height

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am trying to display tabs content in pure css, but i am unable to fix this height for parent. if content is more in tabs content parent content(red area) not expanding. please help to to expanding the parent (red area) when content is more and after clicking on other tab, previous tab content not hidden. please need help in two cases.

```css
.tabs-container {
  background: red;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.tab {
  display: block;
  width: 220px;
}

.tab label {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block
}

.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 220px;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content > * {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  z-index: 2;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content > * {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container">
  <div class="tabs">
    <!--tabs-->
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked="">
      <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
      <!--tabs-content-->
      <div class="content">
        <p>Our expert team allows us to offer Protective Coating services, which is famous for its variety of benefits such as offering universal strainers for light shades, offers breath ability for preventing moisture, curing a tough flexible & abrasion
          resistant coating, resistant to chalking and flaking and offering strong bonding on cement concrete, asbestos & mild steel. Our range of services finds its application in various areas like chajjas, external vertical walls, china mosaic tiles,
          water tanks (externally), sloppy roofs, asbestos roof, roof terraces and stone walls. These services consist of acrylic elastomeric dust proof coating and polyurethane waterproof coatings. Protective Coating Our expert team allows us to offer
          Protective Coating services, which is famous for its variety of benefits such as offering universal strainers for light shades, offers breath ability for preventing moisture, curing a tough flexible & abrasion resistant coating, resistant to
          chalking and flaking and offering strong bonding on cement concrete, asbestos & mild steel. Our range of services finds its application in various areas like chajjas, external vertical walls, china mosaic tiles, water tanks (externally), sloppy
          roofs, asbestos roof, roof terraces and stone walls. These services consist of acrylic elastomeric dust proof coating and polyurethane waterproof coatings.</p>
      </div>
      <!--tabs-content end-->
    </div>

    <!--tabs-->
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1" checked="">
      <label for="tab-2">Tab One</label>
      <!--tabs-content-->
      <div class="content">
        <p>Stuff for Tab One</p>
      </div>
      <!--tabs-content end-->
    </div>

    <!--tabs-->
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1" checked="">
      <label for="tab-3">Tab One</label>
      <!--tabs-content-->
      <div class="content">
        <p>Protective Coating
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--tabs-content end-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**working codepen** [link](http://codepen.io/srinivashappy/pen/xOgJwx?editors=1100)

Comment: Is your tabs fixed or they increased? means only 3 tabs you used or they increased?

Answer (score 0):

for your issue (hope it is inside html and body) then

```
.tabs-container {background: red;padding: 30px;height: 100%;overflow:auto;}
```

will work for you.

[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/malebe/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score -1):

If i understood maybe it

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Add "min-height: 100%;"

Comment: no,its not working, can you give working example so that is is good.@Sergey Grinenko

Comment: UPD: It's works for tags body & html. If parent other tag your're nead fix heigt in JS, or print smaller text

Comment: is there any solution for pure css, i am asking css only answer. please read question and understand. else give working example of fiddle or codepen @Sergey Grinenko.

Comment: Yes, I have read. I am faced with similar, but unfortunately the use position: absolute can not solve this problem by using pure CSS 1) Use JS 2) Cut text 3) Use overflow for text block